# Sequelize multiple delete on multiple columns

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to delete rows based on query of multiple columns, here is my code:

```
var destroyQuery = testArr.map(function(mc){
  return {
    id: mc.id,
    text: mc.text
  }
});
db.testModel.destroy({ where: destroyQuery }).then(function(dResponse){});
```

For deleting one record it works fine:

```
db.testModel.destroy({ where: {id: '123', text: 'abc'} }).then(function(dResponse){});
```

How can i delete multiple rows by querying multiple columns. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your argument "mc" in function, you should use an array like given example below:

```
var kvArray = [{key: 1, value: 10}, 
               {key: 2, value: 20}, 
               {key: 3, value: 30}];

var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj) { 
   var rObj = {};
   rObj[obj.key] = obj.value;
   return rObj;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map check this article. might be it solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I used this option, is fast and simple

```
var destroyQuery = testArr.map(function(mc){
   return {
       id: mc.id,
       text: mc.text
   }
});
db.testModel.destroy({
    where:{
        [Op.or]: destroyQuery 
    } 
}).then(function(dResponse){});
```